# Connecting Dynamics crm with SharePoint

Tags: dynamics-crm, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am creating a console app where I want to connect Dynamics 365 with SharePoint.
I couldn't find anything regarding the same.
Can anyone please help.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pls read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you please provide us more information, Is  your CRM and SharePoint on Premise or Online and what exactly do you wish to achieve here?